# What posix_fadvise() args for sequential file write?

Tags: c, optimization, posix

I am working on an application which does sequentially write a large file (and does not read at all), and I would like to use `posix_fadvise()` to optimize the filesystem behavior.

The function description in the manpage suggests that the most appropriate strategy would be `POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL`. However, the Linux implementation description doubts that:

> Under Linux, `POSIX_FADV_NORMAL` sets the readahead window to the  default  size  for  the  backing  device; `POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL`  doubles  this  size, and `POSIX_FADV_RANDOM` disables file readahead entirely.

As I'm only writing data (overwriting files possibly too), I don't expect any readahead. Should I then stick with my `POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL` or rather use `POSIX_FADV_RANDOM` to disable it?

How about other options, such as `POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE`? Or maybe do not use `posix_fadvise()` for writing at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It all depends on the temporal locality of your data. If your application won't need the data soon after it was written, then you can go with `POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE` to avoid writing to the buffer cache (in a similar way as the `O_DIRECT` flag from `open()`).

Comment: Please note that POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE is not implemented in the linux kernel.

Answer (score 48):

Most of the `posix_fadvise()` flags (eg `POSIX_FADV_SEQUENTIAL` and `POSIX_FADV_RANDOM`) are hints about readahead rather than writing.

There's some advice from Linus [here](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1005.2/01845.html) and [here](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1005.2/01953.html) about getting good sequential write performance.  The idea is to break the file into large-ish (8MB) windows, then loop around doing:

- Write out window N with `write()`;
- Request asynchronous write-out of window N with `sync_file_range(..., SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WRITE)`
- Wait for the write-out of window N-1 to complete with `sync_file_range(..., SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WAIT_BEFORE | SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WRITE | SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WAIT_AFTER)`
- Drop window N-1 from the pagecache with `posix_fadvise(..., POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED)`

This way you never have more than two windows worth of data in the page cache, but you still get the kernel writing out part of the pagecache to disk while you fill the next part.

Comment: Fantastic, this is what I needed to make utee (https://github.com/aktau/utee) not thrash the cache but stay fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as writes go I think that you can just rely on the OSes disk IO scheduler to do the right thing.

You should keep in mind that while `posix_fadvise` is there specifically to give the kernel hints about future file usage patterns the kernel also has other data to help it out.

If you don't open the file for reading then it would only need to read blocks in when they were partially written.  If you were to truncate the file to 0 then it doesn't even have to do that (you said that you were overwriting).